# Django Limiting models based on status

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to create a route to edit a purchase, but editing can only be done if the status of the purchase is "in validation". Does anyone know what Django tool I use to limit a status-based model?

Comment: Can you share your current serializer, view and model (you can remove the non-relevant parts).

Comment: To avoid an editing of purchases must not be edited you can filter your queryset by status. Provide please your code if you need an example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check this document on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a boolean field `in_validation` within your purchase/order model. If your app has an Edit Orders page, you can apply a filter on your database fetch call to show only those orders on the page that have `in_validation == True`.

Also, in your Django view where you implement the edit order logic, you can use a simple if-else check to ensure that the order has `in_validation == True`.

Basically, you just have to edit your model to include an extra field rather than use a separate tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the purchase in your PurchaseSerializer:

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs['status']!="in validation":
        raise ValidationError("You are not allowed to edit a purchase")
    return attrs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation of your PurchaseSerializer and raise a ValidationError if object's status is not "in_validation". But in this case you should care about using this approach for all serializers you're using for editing purchases.

But it would be better if you filter a queryset to avoid an editing of purchases must not be edited:

```py
class PurchaseViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()

        if self.action in ('update', 'partial_update',):
            # remove all items with another statuses
            qs = qs.filter(status=Purchase.Status.IN_VALIDATION)
        return qs
```

If user try to edit a purchase with another status, he just get a 404 response status.